# Flask returning 404 triggers exception block and doesnt return Not Found

Tags: python, flask

I have a very very simple flask server just for learning purposes but what I don't understand is when i `return abort(404)` it triggers the exception block and doesn't actually return the 404 it actually returns:

```
HI 2017-02-16 18:46:27,048 - __main__ - ERROR - Exception on /dddd [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1566, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Flask server code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, jsonify, abort, Response

@application.route("/<short_link>", methods=['GET'])
def get_short_link(short_link):
    try:
        if id_exists(short_link):
            return redirect(find_full_link_by_id(short_link), code=302)
        return abort(404)
    except:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        print("SOME PLACEHOLDER")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

where `id_exists` queries a MySql database, this all works I have tested this in segregation.

My understanding would be that having this:

```
if id_exists(short_link):
            return redirect(find_full_link_by_id(short_link), code=302)
return abort(404)
```

it should always return.

Also my server has a post endpoint which returns a 415 if you don't use `application/json` as the content type. This works as expected:

```
try:
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        full_link = request.get_json(force=True).get('fullLink')
        return jsonify(shortLink=generate(full_link, 5), fullLink=full_link)
    return abort(Response('Unsupported Media Type', 415))
except:
    # Some error handling omitted for this purpose
```

which does correctly return the 415 response. I have tried returning 200, 415, 403 etc just to see if its something special about the 404 but no look.

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to this framework.

EDIT: Just to clarify if I use a debugging tool and update my code to be:

```
 try:
        if id_exists(short_link):
            return redirect(find_full_link_by_id(short_link), code=302)
        return abort(404)
 except Exception as e:
     #do something... removed for the sake of clarity
```

the debugging says the exception (`e`) is actually `404: Not Found` using PyCharm IDE

Comment: Your except block has no return. So when there is an exception in the try block you don't return anything which is precisely what the error message tells you.

Comment: @Wombatz but the exception that gets thrown, is 404: Not Found which comes from the 404, thats what I don't understand. Should it not just return the`abort(404)`. Updated my post to show this

Comment: you should neither return nor catch aborts in Flask. Simply call the abort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`abort()` is a non returning function. It doesn't return because the only thing it does is raise an exception. So the first mistake you are makeing is `return abort(...)`. The `return` is never reached.

The second mistake is the `try except` statement.

1. This is a good example why a bare `except` is bad. Don't do that unless you know for sure that you need it.
2. You explicitly raise an exception and catch that in the `except` block. Why raise in the first place if you catch it directly?

To solve your problem use this pattern:

```
if object_not_found:
    abort(404)
do_something
return your_response
```

Note: it's just `abort` without `return`.

Always make sure your view does return a response.

Your code didn't work because you caught the abort exception in your `except` block and you didn't return a response after that.